# ORACLE Query to return First Row for a DataSet

Tags: sql, oracle, analytics

I'm writing a query which would return first row of a set of grouped data. I tried using OVER  PARTITION BY clause, but somehow I'm not getting the desired result :

```
select  row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY leafv , value_group , l1d ,l2d  ,l3d  ,l4d  ,l5d  ,l6d ,l7d  
order by leafv , value_group , l1d ,l2d  ,l3d  ,l4d  ,l5d  ,l6d ,l7d  
) MYROWNUM ,
S.* 
from
(SELECT 
  NVL(CASE
    WHEN (SELECT parameter_value
      FROM V_CONFIG_PARAMETERS
      WHERE rownum       = 1
      AND parameter_name = 'MOMENT_ITEM_NUMBER_TYPE') = 'S'
    THEN sku
    WHEN (SELECT parameter_value
      FROM V_CONFIG_PARAMETERS
      WHERE rownum       = 1
      AND parameter_name = 'MOMENT_ITEM_NUMBER_TYPE') = 'U'
   THEN upc
    WHEN (SELECT parameter_value
      FROM V_CONFIG_PARAMETERS
      WHERE rownum       = 1
      AND parameter_name = 'MOMENT_ITEM_NUMBER_TYPE') = 'C'
    THEN CUSTOM_PRODUCT_CODE
  END,'NULLVALUE') leafv,
  nvl(chain_name,'NULLVALUE') value_group,
  nvl(level_10_description ,'NULLVALUE') l10d,
  nvl(level_1_description,'NULLVALUE') l1d,
  nvl(level_2_description,'NULLVALUE') l2d,
  nvl(level_3_description,'NULLVALUE') l3d,
  nvl(level_4_description,'NULLVALUE') l4d,
  nvl(level_5_description,'NULLVALUE') l5d,
  nvl(level_6_description,'NULLVALUE') l6d,
  nvl(level_7_description,'NULLVALUE') l7d,
  nvl(level_8_description,'NULLVALUE') l8d,
  nvl(level_9_description,'NULLVALUE') l9d
  FROM t_product_catalog_flat
  order by leafv , value_group , l1d ,l2d  ,l3d  ,l4d  ,l5d  ,l6d ,l7d  ,l8d  ,l9d  ,l10d ) S
  order by MYROWNUM
```

Expected Result :
1 row for each set of data having same value for the group of columns ( leafv , value_group , l1d ,l2d  ,l3d  ,l4d  ,l5d  ,l6d ,l7d  ,l8d  ,l9d  ,l10d)

But I'm getting some weird result, which doesn't match with what I was expecting.
Please suggest the possible solution

Comment: All those ROWNUM = 1 filters will just return one (random!) row from the corresponding tables, before you even get to do anything else with them. Then, the ROW_NUMBER() OVER (....) should be in the inner query; the outer query should only have the WHERE RN = 1 filter.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Could you please expand little more on your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

This query is over DBA_TAB_COLS and grouped by Table Name and Data Type. It pulls back the first grouped row.

Hopefully this not overly simplistic for what you are trying to accomplish.

```
select *
from (
  select  t.TABLE_NAME, t.DATA_TYPE
  from dba_tab_cols t
  where t.OWNER = 'SYS'
  group by  t.TABLE_NAME, t.DATA_TYPE
  order by t.TABLE_NAME, t.DATA_TYPE
)
where rownum = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, It didn't help . There are duplicates for the combination of columns (leafv , value_group , l1d ,l2d ,l3d ,l4d ,l5d ,l6d ,l7d ) 

I want just one row for each of these grouped value.

Answer (score 0):

This query returns the expected result :

SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT row_number() OVER(partition by leafv , value_group , l1d ,l2d ,l3d ,l4d ,l5d ,l6d ,l7d order by leafv , value_group , l1d ,l2d ,l3d ,l4d ,l5d ,l6d ,l7d ) MYROWNUM , 
S.* 
FROM 
(SELECT NVL(SKU, 'NULLVALUE') leafv, 
NVL(chain_name,'NULLVALUE') value_group, 
NVL(level_10_description ,'NULLVALUE') l10d, 
NVL(level_1_description,'NULLVALUE') l1d, 
NVL(level_2_description,'NULLVALUE') l2d, 
NVL(level_3_description,'NULLVALUE') l3d, 
NVL(level_4_description,'NULLVALUE') l4d, 
NVL(level_5_description,'NULLVALUE') l5d, 
NVL(level_6_description,'NULLVALUE') l6d, 
NVL(level_7_description,'NULLVALUE') l7d, 
NVL(level_8_description,'NULLVALUE') l8d, 
NVL(level_9_description,'NULLVALUE') l9d 
FROM test_partition 
ORDER BY leafv , 
value_group , 
l1d , 
l2d , 
l3d , 
l4d , 
l5d , 
l6d , 
l7d , 
l8d , 
l9d , 
l10d 
) S 
) 
WHERE MYROWNUM=1